# Unable to cast PersistentGenericBag to ISet exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am getting this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type `` 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[System.Int64]' `` to type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[System.Int64]' ``

I use:

```
public virtual ISet<long> Ids { get; set; }
```

I am not doing any explicit mapping here using FNH.

Comment: Using Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet explictely seems to do the trick but I read somewhere that nhibernate should be able to cope with .net 4's iset as well ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map your collection as `Bag` you should use `IList<T>` in your entity for collection.

If you map as `Set` then you either can use `ISet<T>` from Iesi.Collections or `ICollection<T>` interface from .NET

Comment: That's what I did and it still does not work (it does not persist). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109438/fluent-nhibernate-problem

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate does not support NET4 ISet out of the box. You need to add [this package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate.SetForNet4).

Comment: Thanks. Can I not just use Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet? See also a related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109438/fluent-nhibernate-problem

Comment: Yes, you can. That's what it's there for. You can also use `ICollection<T>`.